# Inserting a character before a pattern that was defined with a regular expression using BASH

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I want to use something like `sed` or `awk` in GNU-BASH to place a character before a pattern. Data could look like:

```
 $cat file.txt
 Sentence1  
 CATDOGSNAKEHIPPOCHICKENSNAKE
 Sentence1  
 LIONCATSNAKEZEBRAFISH
```

I want to place an `'N'` before the pattern `[A-Z][A-Z]SNAKE` so that I get the following output

```
Sentence1
CATDNOGSNAKEHIPPOCHICKNENSNAKE
Sentence2
LIONCNATSNAKEZEBRAFISH
```

If I try normal substitution it doesn't seem to work with the regex term. I cant use substitution as how would I replace `[A-Z][A-Z]`?

I had found something that adds an `'N'` to the beginning of a line once it finds the pattern:

```
awk '/[A-Z][A-Z]SNAKE/{gsub (/^/,"N")}1'
```

Though I don't know if `sed` or `awk` can only manipulate lines.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler, more portable way to do this:

```
sed 's/[A-Z][A-Z]SNAKE/N&/g' file.txt
```

The `&` character in the replacement substitutes the entire matched pattern, without needing the parentheses or `\1` backreference. This is part of the basic [POSIX `sed` spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), so it should work pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/\([A-Z][A-Z]SNAKE\)/N\1/g' file.txt 
Sentence1  
CATDNOGSNAKEHIPPOCHICKNENSNAKE
Sentence1  
LIONCNATSNAKEZEBRAFISH
```

Comment: Good use of BRE.

Comment: On my OS X machine the -r isn't supported :)

Comment: That's strange, I'd check `man sed` to see if it uses a different option? `sed -h` should tell you as well.

Comment: Both GNU and BSD (macOS) `sed` understand `-E` to invoke extended regex syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Or using extended regular expression with `sed` you can do:

```
sed -r 's/(\w\wSNAKE)/N\1/g' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed -r 's/(\w\wSNAKE)/N\1/g' file.txt
Sentence1
CATDNOGSNAKEHIPPOCHICKNENSNAKE
Sentence1
LIONCNATSNAKEZEBRAFISH
```

Comment: Nice, yes I should have added the ERE version too for education. Thanks.

Comment: @dr-who This was a good question. I had to scratch off what couldn't be used or wouldn't work to arrive at what would. First though was `awk` and `gsub`, but there is nothing similar to the back-reference to work with. Initial thought with `sed` was to anchor and capture either side, but then the multiple occurrences wouldn't work. So finally a global replacement relying on a single back-reference was arrived at. Made you think....

Comment: Thanks! Kind of stupid question as I am still learning, what is ERE and BRE? I hope to get better but this was a good example to learn off of as I was trying to figure out how sed/awk worked.

Comment: Those are just the different categories of Regular Expressions you can make use of. By default `sed` will use *Basic Regular Expressions* (or BRE) [POSIX Basic Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), then you also have *Extended Regular Expression* (ERE) syntax. (same link). The differences are subtle but important. Like for the capture group in BRE you must escape the `\(...\)`, but for ERE you don't `(...)`. ERE provides shorthand for *word-characters*, `\w` while BRE requires the character list `[A-Z]`, etc..

Comment: `\w` represents more than `[A-Z]` so it may give false positives, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions).

Comment: Well yes, it represents `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, but given the dataset it fit. You are correct that with another dataset, there is the chance for false positives.

Comment: Haha, yeah my answer was downrated. I personally prefer to know exactly the ranges that I specify, and tend to always use [A-Z] myself.

Comment: @dr-who There is no rhyme or reason. The sad part is most don't have the integrity to stand behind their downvote by leaving a comment. All we can do is lead-by-example and make SO better by upholding higher standards. The downvote isn't free, it costs the downvoter 1-rep (cost you 2, up to a max of 10 for 5-downvotes). I think your answer is fine. (there I fixed it by adding the UV)